# PoE+ Forward Converter Issues

Tags: dc-dc-converter, poe

I want to implement a 12v PoE+ PD power supply, and have settled on the [LTC4269](http://www.analog.com/en/products/monitor-control-protection/power-over-ethernet-poe-interface-controllers/poe-powered-device/ltc4269-2.html) for use in this application. Unfortunately I'm having problems getting my head around everything that is going on.

A demonstration circuit is available which provides 5v output ([DC1351B](http://www.analog.com/en/design-center/evaluation-hardware-and-software/evaluation-boards-kits/dc1351b.html)) and I have one of these boards. I took some measurements of the startup and ripple at Vout in it's off-the-shelf state at various resistive loads (no load, 15Ω, 7.5Ω, 5Ω, 2.5Ω and 1.25Ω) - needless to say, they all look great.

[Startup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPgq8.png) and [Ripple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crtWO.png) at 1.25Ω / ~4A / ~20W.

---

I then modified it for 12v output (more details at the end), after which it failed to startup, or would fall over under both no load and 30Ω (~400mA / ~4.8W). It also made nasty crackling / clicking sounds...

This screenshot shows a failed start followed by a successful start. Note that this does *not* show the switching frequency, but a much lower frequency component.

[image: 12v startup]

I have a feeling that this is because of flux buildup in the transformer, but I'm really not sure, and this is what I'd like to understand with your help.

Unfortunately I didn't get any measurements of the transformer coil's switched side before my modifications, so I don't have a known "*good*" trace of my own, but a series from afterwards are below. I have ordered another board to keep as a control so that I can compare properly.

---

- **Yellow** is Vout

  - 3v/div, aiming for 12v
- **Blue** is the switched side of the transformer's primary coil (pin 2/3 of T2)

  - 50v/div, the PoE supply is nominally ~54v.

As time progresses, the waveform becomes increasingly distorted. Afterwards (in the last frame, when the switching stops) there is significant oscillation on the transformer.

[image: vout_vs_switched_tx]

A full video of this trace is available [here (YouTube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ULgYGKImkfE), and a wide screenshot of everything is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oin4Y.png) - there are *significant* transients later in the trace...

---

I believe that the **yellow** trace below (from the DC1351B quick start guide) is equivalent to my **blue** above. This implies that ~80v is not unreasonable, and more when the output current step occurs - unfortunately it doesn't show the detail I'd like.

[image: trace from DC1351B]

---

Am I correct in thinking that this is flux buildup? If so, what should be done to avoid it? The duty cycle already appears to be quite low.

I'm still trying to fully understand the Forward Converter topology and the constraints that are in place. I've watched videos from The University of Colorado (e.g: [here](https://www.coursera.org/lecture/converter-circuits/sect-6-3-2-the-forward-converter-M6Bbz)).

---

My modifications to the DC1351B demo circuit are below:

- Replace T2 with PA2649NL

  - originally PA2431NL
  - from the EP13 series - [datasheet](http://productfinder.pulseeng.com/products/datasheets/P675.pdf)
  - note reduced primary inductance from ~429.3µH to ~100.5µH (*I suspect this is very relevant*)
- Replace R29 with 180kΩ

  - target switching frequency of 200kHz
- Replace R20 / R33 potential divider with 13.3kΩ / 1.54kΩ

  - D21 has a 1.24v reference
  - ~11.94v Vout
- Replace R19 with 5.6kΩ - for 12v operation
- Replace R8 with 2kΩ - for 12v operation
- Replace C9 with 16v rated capacitor - for 12v operation

  - 220µF low-ESR (0.1Ω) Tantalum

---

The full schematic (with annotated modifications and probe points marked) is below:

[image: Full schematic with mods and probe points]

---

The transformer windings have gone *from* PA2431NL: (switched input on pins 1 & 2)

[image: PA2431NL windings]

*to* PA2649NL:

[image: PA2649NL windings]

---

Please note, this is largely a learning exercise, and I've not yet been in contact with LT.

Comment: How did you modify it for 12 V? How did you rewind the transformer? What’s the maximum voltage-time area your transformer can take? What’s your duty cycle limit? What’s your output inductance and capacitance? What does your LTspice simulation show?

Comment: Show the circuit; don't describe it and show the exact circuit.

Comment: I've added the full schematic, and will follow up with transformer winding ratios later.

Comment: Apologies for only providing some information earlier - I had to run off. I've now given the new transformer windings too.

Comment: @winny you asked some questions that I'm not immediately sure how to answer - I'll do some reading. I've not reproduced this in LTSpice... yet.

Comment: Good! All of my questions are leading questions in order to lead you towards your problem.

Comment: Couldn't agree more - thanks for the input, I really appreciate it.

Comment: The higher secondary-side turns ratio is likely damaging the self-driven synchronous FETs. What is the voltage on the secondary-side gates? There's some discussion about this at https://ez.analog.com/thread/106810-ltc4269-2-max-current-and-pwrgd

Comment: Good catch, thanks - a quick calculation suggests ~30.5v (the datasheet for the FETs states a 30v max Vds rating and breakdown)... Unfortunately I don't have a trace of this or the hardware right now, but I'll look when I can.

Comment: Can you disable or replace any synchronous rectifier FETs with normal diodes just to rule them out?